# Routing to an index page specific to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a posts model and a users model. Post belong to users. On the users/show page I want to link to this url:

```
/users/1/posts
```

On this page, I will display all the posts created by the user.

I've tried things like

users/show

```
<%= link_to "Posts", posts_path(@user) %>
```

posts/index

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

but this is routing to

```
/posts.1
```

and displaying all posts belonging to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct helper is `user_posts_path(@user)` This requires you have the post resource nested under your user resource in your routes.

In your posts controller you need this code:

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @posts = @user.posts
end
```

Comment: By the way, should I keep my index file in my posts folder or my users folder?

Comment: If by `index file` you mean the index view, then it should go in your posts view folder. Any `posts_controller.rb` action will look in `app/views/posts` for views by default.

Answer (score 1):

The url helper for the link you posted will look like this:

```
user_posts_path(@user) # => /users/123/posts
user_post_path(@user, @post) # => /users/123/posts/1
```

In order to do what you want you will have to add the correct route:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

Then you can see all available url helpers by running the `rake routes` task. They might look like this:

```
users_path GET  /users(.:format)                         users#index
user_path GET  /user/:id(.:format)                       users#show
...
user_posts_path GET  /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)     posts#index
user_post_path  GET  /user/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)  posts#show
...
```

Note that in the `tasks_controller`, the users id will be accessible from the url with `params[:user_id]`

You might want to look over the rails guide on [nested routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)